# when to refesh view UI after async call to a view model to reload data

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, messenger

In my viewmodel i have a command that performs an asynchronous call to a web service to reload data in a view's grid. How do I notify UIViewController in a view once view model completes so that view controller can call ReloadData on UI?
The command does not display a new view, just sets properties that are binded by view.

one of the option I can think of is not make an asynchronous call to a web service from view model and do a call to reloaddata once i return from command.execute() of my command custom binding module? is this the right approach? Perhaps use of messenger?

Thank you
Mark

Comment: Why not just use a NSNotification

Comment: Better than a NSNotification is to use a block on completion of the call.

Comment: Why not just bind to normal C# properties in the ViewModel (e.g. `IsLoaded`) and then let INPC update the UI

Comment: got it, thank you, just took me a few minutes to understand ;~)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RaisePropertyChanged`:

In your ViewModel

`private List<YourDataClass> _yourDataList;
public List<YourDataClass> YourDataList 
{
    get { return _yourDataList; }
    set
    {
        _yourDataList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => YourDataList);
    }
}`

In View

```
private YourViewModel _yourViewModel;
public YourViewConstructor()
{
    //some your code
    _yourViewModel = this.ViewModel as YourViewModel;
    _yourViewModel.PropertyChanged += _yourViewModel_PropertyChanged;

    //some your code
}

void LoginViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("YourDataList "))
    {
        //Refresh List
    }
}
```

`

If your are going just to add new items in your data list then after adding call

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => YourDataList);
```

Comment: Here is also one of the lessons from Stuart - the guy that actually developed MvvmCross for Xamarin - where you can find how the make the binding you list to the tableView: https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-06-Books/

Comment: in the code above, how is _yourViewModel initialized?